# Why is the Coral USB not running when executing own tflite model?

Tags: python, detection, tensorflow-lite, google-coral

Setup: Raspberry PI 4b 4GB with Coral USB accelerator.

I am running [this detection program](https://github.com/google-coral/examples-camera/tree/master/pygame) which is from the official Coral USB website.

Running detection with mobilenet_ssd_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite works at 30FPS.
**And the LED on the Coral USB pulses, [which means the Edge TPU is running](https://coral.ai/docs/accelerator/datasheet/#led-behavior)**.

```
python3 detect.py --model=../all_models/mobilenet_ssd_v2_face_quant_postprocess_edgetpu.tflite --labels=../all_models/coco_labels.txt
```

And the output is a stream of something like this:

```
96% person Inference: 11.99ms FPS:22.9
```

Running mymodel.tflite runs at 3FPS.
**The LED on the coral USB is solid, which means the Coral USB is initialized but not running.**

```
python3 detect.py --model=../all_models/mymodel.tflite --labels=../all_models/dict.txt
```

And the output is a stream of something like tis:

```
85% S_13 Inference: 290.25ms FPS:3.2
```

The examples with gstreamer, pygame and raspicam in the GitHub repo yield the same result (3FPS) and solid light if I run my own model but all run at 30FPS with mobilenet and the LED blinks in all three cases.

I believe the problem has to do with the Coral USB not running when the Raspberry executes my own model, which has these
[specs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FuWRC.png)

**Other stuff**

My labels are in the same format as coco_labels.txt and the detection, even if slow, happens. Thus, the labels do not seem to be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds to me that you haven't pas your model through the [edgetpu_compiler](https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/compiler/#system-requirements).

```
edgetpu_compiler -s mymodel.tflite
```

If it fails, check if your custom model passes the requirements here: https://coral.ai/docs/edgetpu/models-intro/#model-requirements

Comment: This worked to compile the model, thank you. It runs faster but now it does not detect anything. This is the output of the compilation:
**Model successfully compiled but not all operations are supported by the Edge TPU. A percentage of the model will in
stead run on the CPU, which is slower. If possible, consider updating your model to use only operations supported b
y the Edge TPU. For details, visit g.co/coral/model-reqs.
Number of operations that will run on Edge TPU: 132
Number of operations that will run on CPU: 162**

Comment: Oh, is this an AutoML object detection model by anychance?

Comment: It was created using Google Vision and exported selecting the "tflite" option.

Comment: So to answer the question: yes, it is an AutoML object detection. What am I missing?

Comment: Ahh, okay, sorry about that, please send your model over to coral-support@google.com and reference this issue. There are some incompatibility with the released compiler and AutoML, if you send it to us, I'll compile it for you. This will all be fixed after next compiler release!

Comment: That is very kind. Thank you! I will do that.